# Downloading a Large Folder From Google-Drive Using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a large folder with 50000 images from my GDrive into a local server using Python. The following code receives a limitation error. Any alternative solutions?

```
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/135hTTURfjn43fo4f?usp=sharing'  # I'm showing a fake token
gdown.download_folder(url)
```

> Failed to retrieve folder contents:
>
> The gdrive folder with url:
> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/135hTTURfjn43fo4f?usp=sharing
> has at least 50 files,    gdrive can't download more than this limit, if
> you are ok with this,     please run again with --remaining-ok flag.

Comment: I think it looks like you need to use something like this `gdown.download_folder(url, remaining_ok=True)`.

Comment: This won't solve the problem. It will just download the first 50 files in the folder and ignore the rest!

Answer (score 3):

As what kite has mentioned in the comments, use it with the `remaining_ok` flag.

```
gdown.download_folder(url, remaining_ok=True)
```

This wasn't mentioned in https://pypi.org/project/gdown/ so there might be any confusion.

Any references on `remaining_ok` isn't available aside from the warning and [this github code.](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/blob/main/gdown/download_folder.py)

#### EDIT:

Seems like `gdown` is strictly limited to 50 files and haven't found a way of circumventing it.

If other than `gdown` is an option, then see code below.

#### Script:

```
import io
import os
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credential_json = {
    ### Create a service account and use its the json content here ###
    ### https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account
    ### credentials.json looks like this:
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "*********",
    "private_key_id": "*********",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n*********\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "service-account@*********.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "*********",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account%40*********.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credential_json)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

folderId = '### Google Drive Folder ID ###'
outputFolder = 'output'

# Create folder if not existing
if not os.path.isdir(outputFolder):
    os.mkdir(outputFolder)

items = []
pageToken = ""
while pageToken is not None:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="'" + folderId + "' in parents", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken,
                                          fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items.extend(response.get('files', []))
    pageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

for file in items:
    file_id = file['id']
    file_name = file['name']
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    ### Saves all files under outputFolder
    fh = io.FileIO(outputFolder + '/' + file_name, 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(f'{file_name} downloaded completely.')
```

#### References:

- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account

Comment: This won't solve the problem. It will just download the first 50 files in the folder and ignore the rest!

Comment: Are you limited to a gdown solution or anything that works in python will do? as far as I checked, gdown is strictly limited to 50 files. @VahidGhafouri

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround that I used to download urls using gdown

- Go to the drive directory from which you need to download the files
- select all the files using ctrl/cmd A. click on share + and copy all the links
- Now use the following python script to do your job

```
import re
import os
urls = <copied_urls>
url_list = urls.split(', ')
pat = re.compile('https://drive.google.com/file/d/(.*)/view\?usp=sharing')
for url in url_list:
    g = re.match(pat,url)
    id = g.group(1)
    down_url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={id}'
    os.system(f'gdown {down_url}')
```

Note: This solution isn't ideal for 50000 images as the copied urls string will be too huge. If your string is huge, copy it in a file and process it instead of using a variable. In my case I had to copy 75 large files

Answer (score 2):

The download limit is set in `../gdown/download_folder.py`

Comment: Please elaborate your answer with additional details like how user can use the above information e.g. the changes required, build steps, may be a test run results to show if it really works etc.

Comment: This is the best answer. Just change the MAX_NUMBER_FILES = 50 to a large number and should be good after that.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to download CORDv0 from google drive via CLI, and there is no other good way for one line downloading. The **best way** is to save the folder as zip archive to your disk and then download as the unified file.

In some cases, the idea of changing download limit can help. In colab, I used:

```
!pip uninstall gdown --yes
!cd .. && git clone https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown

with open('../gdown/gdown/download_folder.py', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read().replace('MAX_NUMBER_FILES = 50', 'MAX_NUMBER_FILES = 10000')

with open('../gdown/gdown/download_folder.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(code)

!cd ../gdown && pip install -e . --no-cache-dir
!pip show gdown
```

But please remember about gdown errors. As it was aforementioned, gdown lib is not the best choice.

Answer (score -3):

```
!pip uninstall --yes gdown # After running this line, restart Colab runtime.
!pip install gdown -U --no-cache-dir
import gdown

url = r'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sWD6urkwyZo8ZyZBJoJw40eKK0jDNEni'
gdown.download_folder(url)
```